# How can I make link group that look like this image, and how to make that group to my local asset so i cant edit mesh, material, texture of it

Tags: modeling, linked-data, groups, append

[image: here is the image]

I'm blender beginner. I have a blend file called "final". And I have the other blend file call "origin".

1. How can I link the group name beigeBook of the "origin" blend file and add it to the beigeBook of "final" like this Image.
2. How can I make the group link "beigeBook" to my local group completely, so I can edit everything of this group: its object, its mesh, its material, its texture,...from final file and not effect the "origin" file.

Forgive me for my poor english, hope you understand

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the append option, it's similar to link, but this options is like import the group from the original file, so you copy or import the group from the original file and you can edit it in the final file without editing the group from the original file.

[image]

However, you can't edit the textures without edit the original textures because textures aren't part of the .blend file, they are independent files from the .blend file.