# How to unlink a link group completely in blender, so I can edit all mesh data, material, texture of this group

Tags: linked-data, groups

The group I linked from other blend file name "beigeBook" like so in the image below:

1. And I don't know how to make this link group became children of beigeBook object.
2. How can't i unlink this "beigeBook1" completely, so I can edit all mesh data, material, texture of each element of this group

[image: The group I linked from other blend file name "beigeBook" like so in the image below]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make link group that look like this image, and how to make that group to my local asset so i cant edit mesh, material, texture of it](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47601/how-can-i-make-link-group-that-look-like-this-image-and-how-to-make-that-group)

Comment: How is this question different from your earlier question?

Comment: actually, not have different